# How can I open a link in a new tab if it has target=_blank?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to open a link in a new tab only if that link has a `target=_blank` like so.

```html
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

For some reason the `target=_blank` is not working in the a Bootstrap 4.5 navbar Therefore, I am trying to use jQuery to get it to work as some links have the `target=_blank` attribute:

```
$('a.navigation-title').click(function () { 
    location.href = this.href; 
    $(this).find('a').attr('target','_blank'); 
    window.open(this.href, '_blank'); 
  });
```

That's the script I've used, but its not having any effect.

Comment: do you have any browser settings, preventing this from working? It is not possible to force a new tab, if the browser settings says, new links should open in same tab, you will not be able to open a new tab

Comment: @JarlikStepsto - Yes am aware of that browser setting and not I don't have any browser setting that's preventing it from working.

Comment: that's a weird scenario. By default, new pages should open in new tab.

Comment: @Raptor, I know that's why was surprised it was not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('a[target=_blank]');
for (var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
  const element = elements[index];
  element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = element.getAttribute('href');
    if (href) {
      window.open(href, '_blank');
    }
    return false;
  });
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nilesh Chavan, works as expected. Very appreciated

Comment: it's my pleasure. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change code to

`<a href="https://google.com" class="navigation-title" target="_blank">Google</a>`

I have added a new class to the 'a' tag for triggering the click event for jquery

```
$('.navigation-title').click(function () { 
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
    window.open(url , '_blank'); 
  });
```

Comment: I've checked it and the changes you've suggested still don't work. Also I need to check if the _blank attribute exists since its only those that I want to open in a new tab, thanks for the response though.